# Does 32 bit os running on 64 bit cpu support 4Gb ram

Tags: computer-architecture

I want to know if I have a 32 bit OS running on a 64 bit cpu, will it detect or access 4 GB of ram or more

Comment: Generally NO, and XP usually stops at 3.75GB.  There maybe some hacks for certain OS, but generally there a bad idea.

Comment: @cybernard PAE is a perfectly legitimate way to use more than 4 GB of RAM on a 32-bit machine, it's just that consumer editions of Windows aren't licensed to use more than 4 GB. Linux and server editions of Windows will use up to 64 GB of RAM with PAE enabled, hacking other Windows versions to support it has also been shown to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the OS. I know Win 7 has a 4GB limit for 32Bit OS. It will however show you that you have more RAM installed if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

The MB has to support full 4GB RAM with memory remap enabled -- on newer MB this option is usually on by default and can't be adjusted by user, without it, you can't get full 4GB even on a 64bit OS.

[Enable the memory remapping feature](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/978610)

> Check the BIOS settings to see whether the memory remapping feature is
>   enabled. Memory remapping gives Windows access to more memory. You can
>   enable the memory remapping feature in the BIOS by booting to the
>   system setup. See the User's Guide for your computer for instructions
>   on how to boot to system setup on your computer. The name for the
>   memory remapping feature may be different for different hardware
>   vendors. This can be listed as memory remapping, memory extension, or
>   something similar. Be aware that your computer may not support the
>   memory remapping feature.

And if the 32bit OS supports [PAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) -- Windows Server or Linux -- it can access/use full 4GB RAM.